# isreachable(int timeout) doesn't work with android

Tags: java, android, networking

I want to lookup every device that is connected to my local WIFI network. If a device responds to the ping, I will look if it's an android device or not. If it is, the adress will be added to an arraylist. But for some reason android devices don't respond to the command, in windows console, they do, but not in code. All the computers in the house are detected, but my 2 phones aren't, they aren't in standby mode could that be an issue.
I looked it up, I saw that the API isn't capable of using that methode on android devices, but that seems kind of weird. This is the code i'm using:

```
try {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    // this code assumes IPv4 is used
    byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();

    for (int i = this.startIp; i <= this.startIp + 10; i++) {
        ip[3] = (byte)i;
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
        if (address.isReachable(250)) {
            System.out.println(address + " machine is turned on and can be pinged");
        }
        else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName())) {
            System.out.println(address + " machine is known in a DNS lookup");
            if(address.getHostName().contains("android")) {
                androidIpAdresses.add(address);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(address + " the host address and host name are equal, meaning the host name could not be resolved");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

isReachable() may use ICMP PING or it might use TCP ECHO (port 7), in which case some devices might not respond.  Use wireshark to see which is the case.

Comment: But what if it doesn't respond to what isReachable() uses? is there another way of contacting an android device using java code? Mayby using bash command reading the output if that's possible?

Comment: checkout http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html